# Are there any other examples of DSL in powershell?

Tags: powershell, dsl, abstraction

[**PowerBoots**](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/karl-prosser/archive/2009/02/11/powerboots-a-beautiful-dsl-not-to-mention-useful.aspx) is a very useful example of DSL which exploits script blocks to create GUIs:

```
Boots {
   StackPanel {
      Button "A bed of clams"
      Button "A coalition of cheetas"
      Button "A gulp of swallows"
   }
}
```

I know that without specifying a target **Domain** this question appears very general. So I'm going to make it more specific:

Do you know any other project implementing a kind of DSL in powershell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should also look at psake: https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake

Also, I just found Pester, which is the PoSh answer for RSpec: https://github.com/pester/Pester

Answer (score 6):

Another example: [Windows PowerShell: A Better XML](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/17/use-powershell-to-simplify-working-with-xml-data.aspx)

Comment: PowerShell Pack has WPK which is anotherDSL exampl like PowerBoots http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack. Boots and WPK are merging into Show-UI: The PowerShell WPF Toolkit http://showui.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://huddledmasses.org/a-dsl-for-xml-in-powershell-new-xdocument/)'s an example of a DSL for XML in PowerShell.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/10/09/domain-specific-languages-dsls-in-general-and-how-powershell-relates.aspx)'s a blog post by Jeffrey Snover about DSLs in PowerShell (look at the comments for more links).

Answer (score 0):

I tried PowerShell as DSL script for a C#.Net application and my experience has posted [here.](http://joymonscode.blogspot.in/2013/01/dsl-demo-first-c-application-which-uses.html) .PowerShell is really powerful when it comes to DSL world.